# text overlapping in span when too long for viewport

Tags: html, css, text

On the header of my webpage, the text overlaps when it gets too long for the viewport.

This is the HTML code:

```html
<h3 class="col s12 light-blue-text text-darken-4 content-header">
    <span style="position: relative;">
        Mice, fusilli and thin skin
    </span>            
</h3>
```

And this is the CSS class content-header (I'm using the materialize.css framework so don't worry about the `col s12 light-blue-text` and `text-darken-4` classes.)

```
.content-header {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #020202;
    line-height: 0.1em;
    margin: 10px 0 20px;
}

.content-header span {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

This class adds a little line before and after the header.

This is the output I get:
[Output in responsive mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g322.png)

It should make a wordwrap when it doesn't have enough space.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: @j08691 He is using `materialize`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's due to your `line-height: 0.1em;` setting for `.content-header`: The second line's baseline is only 0.1em below the first one's that way, causing the overlap when the text wraps. So change that to `line-height: 1.1;` or similar, at least for screens below a certain width, using a media query.

```css
.content-header {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #020202;
    line-height: 1.1;
    margin: 0px 0 20px;
}

.content-header span {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top:1.1em;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="col s12 light-blue-text text-darken-4 content-header">
    <span style="position: relative;">
        Mice, fusilli and thin skin
    </span>            
</h3>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I think i wasn't clear here: I want the line to be on the left and on the right of the text (on half way) like on the picture I posted.

Comment: I told you the reason why the text overlapped - that was your question. You won't be able to solve that without  a reasonable line-height setting...

Comment: ok so I used a media query to remove the border and set a new line-height. It's not perfect, but it works. Thanks